# How can I create a MongoDB based on MySQL schema?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, schema

How can I create a MongoDB based on MySQL schema?

This is my schema:

```
productCode VARCHAR(15)
productName VARCHAR(70)
productLine VARCHAR(50)
productScale VARCHAR(10)
productVendor VARCHAR(50)
productDescription TEXT
quantityInStock SMALLINT(6)
buyPrice DOUBLE
MSRP DOUBLE
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses flexible schema and you do not have to predeclare your field types in the database. MongoDB (as at 3.0) does not provide any server-side schema validation, so it's perfectly allowable to have a field with different types within the same collection or to have fields vary by document within the same collection.

Schema declaration & validation is optional, but if you want to enforce types you would have to do so via your application logic. There are analogous MongoDB [BSON field types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) for most RDBMS column types, but also obvious differences. For example, MongoDB has a `String` field which stores variable length text (up to ~16MB) rather than distinct `VARCHAR(..)` and `TEXT` types.

In general you will not want to use identical schema when exporting data from a relational database to MongoDB: you would instead consider how best to model your data to support common use cases. For a more complete overview including concepts and examples please refer to the [Data Modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) section in the MongoDB manual.

You have many options to migrate data, for example:

- using client drivers to read/write from your source & target databases
- exporting to a CSV or JSON format which can be read by the [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) command line tool
- using an ETL tool